# SplashScreen is not navigating user to other page

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  doSomeAsyncStuff() async {

    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);

    if (user == null) {
      return LoginScreen();
    } else {
      return BusinessList();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/ledgerslogofinal.png',
          width: 250,
          height: 250,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the working code in stateless widget

```
class WidgetTree extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      return LoginScreen();
    }
    return BusinessList();
  }
}
```

My SplashScreen is not navigating to corresponding pages when user is not available and also for available. I am using the same code in stateless widget which is working but I want to make it work in splash screen. How can I do this?

Comment: have you tried making your inti `async`? and putting await before the call

Comment: because you are using an async without the await.

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  doSomeAsyncStuff() {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      return LoginScreen();
    } else {
      return BusinessList();
    }
  }

Comment: i have changed  like this

Comment: but still not working

Comment: In your stateless widget you're actually returning a widget in the build method (LoginScreen/BusuinessList).
Whereas in your stateful widget you're simply calling "doSomeAsyncStuff" without actually doing anything with the widget returned.
If you attempt to move between screens, I suggest using the Navigator instead.

Comment: if (user == null) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);

      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => BusinessList(),
          ));
    }

Comment: i have changed it.but still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<void> init() async {
    await doSomeAsyncStuff();
}
```

And then call your method in initState method.

Comment: @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    await doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  doSomeAsyncStuff() {
    User user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if (user == null) {
      return LoginScreen();
    } else {
      return BusinessList();
    }
  }

Comment: i have changed like this

Comment: pages are not changing the screen remains in splashscreen itself

Comment: @Vishali Can you debug your method where you initialize user?